# python regex: re.findall() not behaving as expected with alternation

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code:

```
testREString = '(hello | goodbye) \s darkness \s my \s old \s friend'
testString = 'sound of silence: goodbye darkness my old friend'
exp = re.compile(testREString, re.VERBOSE)
print(exp.findall(testString))
```

and it returns: `['goodbye']` where I had expected it to return the full sentence - in fact, using `exp.search(testString)` it had picked out the rest of the sentence correctly. Why then, was the complete match not displayed?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Because `(...)` is a capturing group, and [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns the content of the capturing groups if you defined any. Make it a non-capturing group `(?:...)`

Comment: To make it non-capturing, just add `?:` at the beginning of the parentheses. [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(...)` in a regular expression defines a capturing group.

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns the content of the capturing groups if your expression defines any.

You can make it a non-capturing group `(?:hello|goodbye)` to avoid this. See [What is a non-capturing group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon)

Answer (score 2):

khelwood has explained why findall() behaves this way. If you want to catch the whole match without changing the regex, use

```
exp.group(0)
```